# Help with graph induction question?

Tags: graph-theory, induction

Given a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices, where $n$ is even, prove by induction that if every vertex has degree $n/2 + 1$, then $G$ must contain a 3-cycle. A 3-cycle is a set of 3 vertices, $a; b; c$ such that $ab$ is an edge, $bc$ is an edge and $ac$ is an edge.

Comment: You might want to add the graph-theory tag.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Suppose not, and let $G$ be a minimal counterexample. Let $G$ have $2m$ vertices, each of degree greater than $m$. Let $v$ be any vertex of $G$, and let $w$ be any vertex such that $vw$ is an edge. Let $G'$ be the graph that remains after you remove the vertices $v$ and $w$ and all edges incident at them. Use the fact that $G$ contains no triangle to show that for each vertex $u$ of $G'$, $$\deg_{G'}(u)\ge\deg_G(u)-1\ge m-1$$ and get the contradiction that $G$ wasn’t actually a **minimal** counterexample.

(You can recast this as a proof by induction on $m$ in the usual style, if you want; it’s the same proof either way, with almost identical details.)

Comment: I understand why its true, but i cant seem to do it with induction. I just dont know how i would put a counterexample in a induction proof.

Comment: @Zain: It’s the same thing: as far as I’m concerned, the argument that I outlined **is** a proof by induction. But if you really want to recast it in the traditional style, get the induction off the ground with $m=1$ (two vertices). Now assume that it’s true for $2(m-1)$ vertices, and use my argument to show that it must be true for $2m$ vertices: if there were a counterexample with $2m$ vertices, that argument would give a counterexample with $2(m-1)$ vertices, contradicting the induction hypothesis (or, in my version, the assumption that my counterexample was minimal).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Can you explain the reasoning behind `degG′(u)≥degG(u)−1≥m−1`, is this the core contradiction? What is the significance of degG', degG - 1, and m-1. How are you able to conclude that `degG' >= degG - 1`?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Does the contradiction arise based on the handshaking lemma? Even amount vertices with odd degree is even?

Comment: @GivenPie: Since $G$ has no triangles, there is no vertex $u$ in $G$ such that both $uv$ and $uw$ are edges of $G$. Thus, when we remove $v$ and $w$ and the edges attached to them, we’re removing at most one edge going from them to any other vertex of $G$ and therefore reducing the degree of any other vertex of $G$ by at most $1$. Thus, $\deg_{G'}(u)\ge\deg_G(u)$ for each vertex $u$ of $G'$. And by hypothesis $\deg_G(u)\ge m$ for each vertex $u$, so $\deg_G(u)-1\ge m-1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Hmm, I don't quite see why we are removing at most one edge. Shouldn't the $deg_{G'}(u)$ be less than $deg_{G}(u)$ since $G'$ is the graph with vertices $v$ and $w$ removed? Since you removed edges that incident to them, then it also lower then degree of edges incident to $u$.

Comment: @GivenPie: There’s a typo in my last comment, as you can see if you compare it with the answer: it should say that $\deg_{G'}(u)\ge\deg_G(u)-1$. The two degrees may be equal for some vertices of $G'$, since there’s no reason to think that every vertex of $G'$ was connected to $v$ or $w$, but the important thing is that it cannot be less than $\deg_G(u)-1$, since $u$ is definitely **not** connected to both $v$ and $w$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I'm a tiny bit confused now. Can check if my understanding is correct with you? Since the proof is suppose G is not a triangle we have used a counter example to prove G has triangles. Because of $deg_{G'}(u) \leq deg_{G}(u)-1 \leq m-1$ for a case of $m = 2$, this holds true. In the end, there are triangles in graph g.

Comment: @GivenPie: No, that’s not the logic of the argument. The assumption that we make in order to get a contradiction is that $G$ is a **minimal** counterexample, meaning that if another graph $H$ satisfies the hypotheses of the theorem and has fewer vertices than $G$, then $H$ **does** have a triangle. We then show that we can remove one vertex from $G$ to get $G'$, a graph with fewer vertices, in such a way that $G'$ has no triangle. This contradicts the minimality of $G$, and we conclude that the theorem has no counterexamples at all (because if it had one, it would have a smallest one).

Answer (score 1):

Proof by induction means proving a base case and then proving that if true for x it is true for x +1. Since we are only interested in in even numbers of vertices that would mean proving that if true for n vertices it is also true for n + 2 vertices.

Given graph G with n vertices where n is even and greater than 3 and every vertex has (n/2)+1 edges.

Our base case is n = 4. With n = 4 each vertex has (4/2)+1 = 3 edges. This means that every vertex is connected to every other vertex by an edge. Thus any combination of 3 vertices will be a 3 cycle.

Inductive step. If true for n = k then true for n = k+2.

With k vertices: each of the k vertices has (k/2)+1 edges attached to it and each edge connects 2 vertices so the graph as a whole has (k((k/2)+1))/2 total edges in it. A graph with k+2 vertices will increase the number of edges in the graph by (((k+2)(((k+2)/2)+1))/2) - ((k((k/2)+1))/2). (the number in the larger graph - number in the smaller graph). We can simplify this to k+2 additional edges in the graph.

Since our graph with k vertices had a 3-cycle (our inductive assumption) we must remove at least one of those edges from that graph. Each vertex, except the 2 new ones and the two connected by the edge we removed, need one new edge attached to them. The two vertices that were connected by the edge we removed need 2 new edges, and the two new vertices will each need ((k+2)/2)+1 new edges.

Adding the edge removed from the graph with k vertices to the number of additional edges that we have to add, we need to add k+3 edges to the graph. If we add a new edge between any of the original k vertices we will be creating a 3-cycle. (we have accepted as true that with all the edges in a graph of k a 3-cycle was created, even if the edge removed broke the only one 3-cycle then a new one would be formed by placing an edge somewhere else among the original k vertices). Since we can't place a new edge between any 2 of the original k vertices each of them must connect to one of the new vertices. If we connect each of the original k vertices to one of the new vertices we have placed k of the edges and have 3 edges left to place. The two vertices that were connected by the edge we removed and the two new vertices are the only ones that can accept a new edge. Each of the two vertices that were part of the orignal k vertices can only accept one edge and each is connected to at least one of the two new vertices. We are left with 4 vertices we can connect edges to and 5 edges connecting those 4 vertices (the 3 we haven't placed plus the 2 already placed between the old and new vertices) plus we can't connect the two old vertices together. 5 edges placed among 4 vertices means that while 2 of the 4 are connected to only two other vertices the other 2 vertices are connected to all 3 of the other vertices and those two will create an 3 cycle with on of the other two.

Proof complete.

Someone else may be able to write it out clearer but it is all here.

Comment: The statement is true even for $n=2$, because there is no simple graph on $2$ vertices with degree $2$, thus no possible counterexample.

Comment: I see what you are saying, with formal logic if A then B is always true if A is false. Also I forgot that unqualified designation of graph usually means simple graph. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @EdwardGoodson: It really helps readability to format using MathJax (see FAQ). Regards

Comment: What you are calling a proof by induction is only one kind of proof by induction. [Structural induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_induction) is another, and indeed is the most appropriate kind here. And all of them can be stated in terms of minimal counterexamples, as in my answer.

Comment: @Amzoti Thanks for the info. on MathJax I hadn't found that yet. Brian, I did not intend any comment on your answer with my answer. I did find the article on structural induction very interesting.