# Proving a Graph contains a $3$-cycle.

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

> Given a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices, where $n$ is even, prove that if every vertex has degree $\frac{n}{2}+1$, then $G$ must contain a $3$-cycle. (A $3$-cycle is a set of $3$ vertices, $a$; $b$; $c$ such that $ab$ is an edge, $bc$ is an edge and $ac$ is an edge.)

Comment: Please use a descriptive question title.

Comment: Since you're new here, I'd like to share some things about Math.SE.  **Firstly**, it would help if you show what you have already tried. This helps us know where you got stuck, and allows us to better answer your question. **Secondly**, we use $\LaTeX$ to format math on this site.  I've edited the question to incorporate this--take a look, and try to use this for future questions; using $\LaTeX$ increases the chances that you get high-quality answers.  For help with $\LaTeX$, see [this meta question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I've edited your question to use $\LaTeX$.  Please make sure it still represents your original intent.

Comment: This is a possible duplicate (verbatim) of [Help with graph induction question?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341100/help-with-graph-induction-question). This question has appeared a number of times, at least two other times in the last day, [e.g. here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341236/3-cycle-discrete-math?lq=1)